# Auto Create Contact from Custom Object using Process Builder - Help

Tags: custom-object, process-builder

We would like to use Process Builder and not Apex for this request.

We have a custom object called "Prospecting Checklist" and it is used by our sales team to gather prospecting information. One section of the checklist has Contact fields (First and Last Name, Title, Phone and Email).

There are 4 Contacts fields:
**Contact 1 - First Name, Last Name, Title, Email
Contact 2 - First Name, Last Name, Title, Email
Contact 3 - First Name, Last Name, Title, Email
Contact 4 - First Name, Last Name, Title, Email**

If a user enters contact information(see above), we want that information to be populated in a new contact record.

Basically after the record is saved, take that contact information, create a contact and populate with those fields.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to build in Process Builder..

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Here is a good guidance https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/business_process_automation/process_builder

Comment: In addition to @OlesMalkov excellent recommendation to go to Trailhead to learn how to use process builder, I'd highly recommend you consider entering these "contacts" as Leads instead. Contacts should ideally be associated with an account. If you're not creating an account for them, then that's what Leads are for until you've "qualified" them and are ready to do business with them and can make them a customer.